# How to call a class so it executes the init() inside the class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a class called DataSource and a init() inside the class that initialize some functions that reads data from a JSON file.

The init() inside the class DataSource is executed when I open my app in the simulator.
But when I then update the JSON file, when I am in the simulator, I want the functions that reads from the JSON file initialized again.

How do I call a Class so it runs the init() within the class again.

```
 import Foundation

struct Post:Codable,Identifiable {
    var userId:Int
    var id:Int
    var title:String
    var body:String
}

class DataSource {
    
    init() {
        if let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "posts", withExtension: "json"),
           let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
            self.allPosts = getPostsFromData(fileData)
            print("The init of DataSource has been called")
        }
    }
```

Best Regards,
Christian Skjøth

Comment: Instead of putting your reading code inside `init`, put it in a different function and call that function from `init`. Then, you can call it again later from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was easy and it worked.